# Simultaneous multithreading processor

Tags: processor, cpu-architecture

I have some doubts and would appreciate if anyone can help me to understand.

Assuming that I have a processor with 8 cores; with 4 way simultaneous multithreading (SMT) provided for each core. Now, I learned that, in case of SMT, each core can issue multiple instructions from different threads or from a single thread. So, in that case, each core should be able to issue at most 4 (as it is 4 way SMT) instructions in every cycle. Hence as there are in total 8 cores in the chip, at every cycle it should be able to issue 8*4 = 32 instructions in ideal case if all the issue slots (i.e.4 for each core) are stall free.

Is there is anything wrong in my reasoning or understanding? I am not an expert! So, would like to discuss about it and learn more. :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: This site is not a good place for discussions, check the faq in the upper right corner...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *n-way SMT* processor can execute instructions from up to n threads. That does not imply any limit on how many instructions in total it can issue in each cycle. If you want to specify this limit you talk about *n-way superscalar* or *n-way issue*.

E.g. Intel's Core i7 is a 4-way superscalar and 2-way SMT processor.